# ST_GeomFromText incomplete output

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

Hi guys im into postgis from a couple of weeks.

I've got a problem with this sql query (trying to make some polygons for exercise):

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((13.399242 45.753833, 13.386882 45.780177, 13.392204 45.803039, 13.411258 45.815842, 13.426365 45.813569, 13.442844 45.788078, 13.399242 45.753833))',4326);
```

the output i get is:

```
"0103000020E6100000010000000700000017618A7269CC2A40A2D288997DE0464078D2C26515C62A40B30B06D7DCE3464084B872F6CEC82A40CE3461FBC9E64640CE6F986890D22A40045ABA826DE846406E5166834CDA2A400C056C0723E84640AB75E272BCE22A403A596ABDDFE4464017618A7269CC2A40A2D288997DE046 (...)"
```

so my answer is: **why is something missing in the output?**

if i use less points (one less) in the sql query wrote before i have no problems (as shown below)

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((13.399242 45.753833, 13.386882 45.780177, 13.392204 45.803039, 13.411258 45.815842, 13.426365 45.813569, 13.399242 45.753833))',4326);


"0103000020E6100000010000000600000017618A7269CC2A40A2D288997DE0464078D2C26515C62A40B30B06D7DCE3464084B872F6CEC82A40CE3461FBC9E64640CE6F986890D22A40045ABA826DE846406E5166834CDA2A400C056C0723E8464017618A7269CC2A40A2D288997DE04640"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks man , it worked :D
now how do i set this question as answered? (and give you some reputation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pgAdmin limits the length of each column.

This limit can be changed in the Query Tool options.

```
File -> Options -> Query Tool -> Max. Characters per column
```

http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/options-query_tool.html